# Blocking SYN-Flood Attacks?

Tags: network, security, tcp, macos

I've got a Mac web server that's been getting hit pretty regularly with `SYN` half-open attacks. I've looked in to various ways to combat this. I've found a lot of general information, but not very much specific information.

The "easiest" approach seems to be tweaking tcp settings in `sysctl.conf`, but I'm having a hard time finding any kind of documentation of these settings. I probably want to increase the total number of available half-open connections, I probably want to reduce the timeout for those connections too, but this is a topic that's not very well documented.

Some of the things I've read suggest you shouldn't raise the half-open connection count limit too high because it uses up more memory. But how much memory can an half open connection really consume? A few bytes? Even if it's 1KB each, my server has 24 GB. Right now the server's limit is 512 half-open connections but I feel like tens of thousands should be no sweat, unless there is some other factor I'm not aware of? Which is very possible because again, so little documentation.

Moving on, another approach is `SYN` Proxying/`SYN` Cookies. These methods remember the details of a syn request, then drop it. Then re-opens it again if the responding `ACK` ever comes. I don't really see how that is functionally different than just opening the connections directly anyway, it seems like that is how TCP should work so it is inherently resistant to these `SYN` attacks. But that's beside the point.....

So the easiest way to use `SYN` Proxying for me is to enable it in my `pf` firewall. But when I try, it doesn't seem to work properly. I did eventually read something that said synproxying in `pf` doesn't work properly on macOS. Another topic with very little documentation.

The other option is to use syncookies, enabled in `sysctl.conf`. I haven't tried this yet. Part of the reason is because both syncookies and synproxying always have disclaimers about how you shouldn't use it constantly, only when you are under attack etc. Well, ignoring the fact that once you are under attack, it is too late to enable syncookies, I also would really like some elaboration on that warning! That sounds very important. WHY would you not want to use proxying or cookies all the time? What are the downsides if I do?

The `SYN` half-open attack does not seem particularly complicated, I'm surprised there aren't easier ways to mitigate it. To be honest, I'm surprised it wasn't all but eliminated with changes to the way all TCP functions.

Comment: Another thought I had is that I have a script that periodically pings other servers to determine if it is offline or not. So if there was a command to flush away all connections stuck in a half open or half closed state, I could run that whenever I detect trouble. Not a perfect solution but it would be a great temporary one while I try to figure out a permanent one.